# Is there a mistake in 'The Potter Family' by J.K. Rowling?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling, pottermore

I was reading [The Potter Family](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-potter-family)
by J.K. Rowling when I believe I came across a mistake in the end. The last paragraph says that:

> Fleamont and Euphemia lived long enough to see James marry a Muggle-born girl called Lily Evans, but not to meet their grandson, Harry. Dragon pox carried them off within days of each other, due to their advanced age, and James Potter then inherited Ignotus Peverell’s Invisibility Cloak.

It says that James inherited the Invisibility Cloak **after** he marries Lily and after Hogwarts. But doesn't that contradict the fact that the Marauders went under the cloak every full moon? Remus Lupin says in the POA:

> They sneaked out of the castle every month under James’s Invisibility Cloak.

Specifically ***James's*** Invisibility Cloak.

Comment: thats not really a mistake, he had the cloak but iwas still his familys, once they died he now "owned" the cloak.

Comment: Guessing, but the same crew that had the yuks to make the map and screw around, probably would have had no problem "borrowing" the cloak.

Comment: But it doesn't say his families cloak, it says *his cloak*

Comment: @Radhil J.K. usually specifies when something was "borrowed" to paint the picture of a character's personality. In this case, that wasn't said.

Comment: when your in highschool and you drive your parents car, your friends arnt like, lets drive around in himarms moms car, there like yo, lets drive around in himarms car, even though technicly its still owned by my mom.

Comment: Again, J.K. tends to explain these types if things in details.

Comment: again jk tends to forget what she wrote 5 minutes later.

Comment: @himarm - I have visions of you driving around in a station wagon with a pink steering-wheel cover.

Comment: @Valorum i drove a maroon/purple minivan, that i could take the back seats out of if needed, bowchicabowwow

Comment: @Himarm  - "TO  THE HIMARM-MOBILE!". "Do you mean your mum's minivan?". "Just shut it, OK?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more a matter of speech than anything to do with the actual ownership.

Early on in the book series, it's more often referred to as Harry's *father's* cloak

> *‘D’you think he meant you to do it?’ said Ron. **‘Sending you your
> father’s Cloak and everything?’***
>
> *‘Well,’ Hermione exploded, ‘if he did – I mean to say – that’s
> terrible – you could have been killed.’*
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone**</sup></sub>

As time goes on, the characters (and author) tend to refer to it as "*Harry's cloak*", one assumes because diehard readers will already have some idea of its provenance and casual readers will be confused if you suddenly introduce a new character mid-conversation.

> *Crabbe blundered forwards, his long arms outstretched like a zombie.
> Harry dodged around him, picked up a stick, and lobbed it at Crabbe’s
> back. Harry doubled up with silent laughter as Crabbe did a kind of
> pirouette in mid-air, trying to see who had thrown it. As Ron was the
> only person Crabbe could see, it was Ron he started towards, but Harry
> stuck out his leg. **Crabbe stumbled – and his huge, flat foot caught
> the hem of Harry’s Cloak.** Harry felt a great tug, then the Cloak slid
> off his face.*
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban**</sup></sub>

and

> *‘What about the Cloak, though?’ said Ron slowly. ‘Don’t you realise,
> he’s right? **I’ve got so used to Harry’s Cloak and how good it is, I
> never stopped to think.** I’ve never heard of one like Harry’s. It’s
> infallible. We’ve never been spotted under it –’*
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows**</sup></sub>